# What are the differences between "a plate of gold" & "a plate in gold"?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

Ok, in [cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/of)

> **of**: preposition (MADE OF): made or consisting of; having:
>
> dresses of lace and silk
>
> plates of gold and silver
>
> a land of ice and snow
>
> a woman of great charm
>
> a subject of very little interest

in [Longman dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/in)

> in /ɪn/ ●●● S1 W1 preposition
>
> 18: used to say what colour something is or **what it is made of**
>
> Do you have the same pattern in blue?
>
> a sculpture in white marble

SO, based on the dictionaries, we can say "**a plate of gold**" & "**a plate in gold**". "**I ordered a dress in cotton**" & "**I ordered a dress of cotton**"

What are the differences between "**a plate of gold**" & "**a plate in gold**"?

Comment: We use "in" with sculpture to specify the material because "of" is used to indicate the subject matter of the sculpture. E.g. A sculpture **of** the Virgin Mary **in** marble.

Comment: This is similar to saying a *plate* ***of*** *sandwiches*, meaning that there are sandwiches *on* the plate, not that the plate is ***made of*** sandwiches. (Meanwhile, *a plate* ***in*** *sandwiches* would likely be interpreted to mean *a plate* ***buried among*** *sandwiches* rather than its material composition. So, the context is important too.)

Comment: In the jewellers, for example, you might be looking at a nice ***silver*** ring. In which context you could reasonably ask *Do you have this ring **in** gold?* Where most likely you'd actually mean ***made of the metal gold***. But the corresponding question in a clothing boutique *(Do you have this dress in gold?)* would obviously mean ***in the colour gold***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following sentence:

> Michelangelo sculpted his captives in marble.

The choice of preposition there is driven by the verb **sculpted**, just as we would say "*wrote* his thesis **in** red ink".

The object of preposition **in** is a *medium* (of expression).

Whereas

> Archeologists discovered several statues made of marble.

There, again, the choice of preposition is driven by the verb, **made**. The object of preposition **of** is a *substance* or *material*.

What is the difference between a substance and a medium? It's the same difference as the difference between the naked and the nude.